# Retag - Get rid of meta tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I've removed all traces of the `subjective` tag from Pro Webmasters. Fortunately, no questions had this tag as the only one.

I also re-tagged one instance of `poll` to `visitor-poll`.

Can anyone else find / rename any [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)?

I do plan to start looking at single use tags next week, but I'd like to join the rest of the SE sites now as far as cleaning out the meta tags.

**Update 1**

The `website` tag has also been removed, as every question on PW is going to be about a web site, which makes the tag about as useful as `question`.

**Update 2**

`best-practice` <strike>is soon to be</strike> removed. It does nothing to describe the actual content of the question

Comment: Not sure the `poll` tag should have been changed. I mean, the tag is about polls on web sites, it doesn't mean the question itself is a poll question.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - That is exactly the point. Any tag (standing alone) should describe the question. Is it a poll _here_ or talking about a poll on their own site?

Comment: I see your point, but we wouldn't allow the `poll` tag for use on poll-type questions (if the questions themselves are even allowed), so `poll` would always describe a visitor/website poll. No matter though.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - Yeah, I see your point. It's only one instance (of either) so feel free to change it. Synonyms (should) work out the rest as time goes on.